# Getting version from pom in JSP for Spring Boot Web

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I was trying to print the application version from pom.xml in my JSP pages. i tried combing the filtering with Spring boot.
But the values are not rendered in the jsp pages.

I added the below section in pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/resources/templates</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And addded the below in jsp pages:-

```
<h4>${project.description}</h4>
<h4>${project.name}</h4>
<h4>${project.version}</h4>
```

But when the JSP page renderes the tags are empty with no values in it.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve very same issue: basically to insert value of project variables statically into JSP generated at build time. Without additional call to get properties etc at run time. Here is a snippet that solved it for me. 
I am using spring and it is using maven-war-plugin underneath.

I put all files that I need static values into subfolder so not all jsps are filtered. Later I static include such files.

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/version/</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF/jsp/version/</targetPath>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

As [described in the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven), Spring Boot uses `@…@` as the delimiter rather than `${…}`:

> since the default config files accept Spring style placeholders (${…​}) the Maven filtering is changed to use @..@ placeholders (you can override that with a Maven property resource.delimiter)

This means that your JSP needs to contain the following:

```
<h4>@project.description@</h4>
<h4>@project.name@</h4>
<h4>@project.version@</h4>
```

Also, AFAIK, filtering for `src/main/resources/templates` should be enabled like this:

```
<resources>
     <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources/templates</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```